# How to reshape dataframe by extracting partial name of header in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am not sure how to reform a data frame with the certain columns based on part of header's name.

Here is data frame I've got.

[image: example of my dataframe]

```
Date        990986_125001_AA1234  990986_125002_AB2586  990986_125003_AA1234
2020-01-01           439.9                398.9                435.8 
2020-05-25           443.8                390.9                438.8  
2020-09-11           438.9                387.9                436.8     
2020-03-27           435.2                399.2                431.5
2020-07-30           434.6                387.2                422.5
2020-08-05           432.7                377.1                432.7
```

I want to form a three separate data frame based on the header.
for example df1 should only contains columns starting with 990986_125001_******
df2 should only contains columns starting with 990986_125002_******
df3 should only contains columns starting with 990986_125003_******

The sepearator is middle number (12500*) so df1 ends with 1 and df2 ends with 2 and df3 ends with 3.
I have 100 of columns.

The desired output will be

```
df1
Date        990986_125001_AA1234  
2020-01-01           439.9       
2020-05-25           443.8
2020-09-11           438.9
2020-03-27           435.2             
2020-07-30           434.6           
2020-08-05           432.7
```

second dataframe

```
df2
Date          990986_125002_AB2586  
2020-01-01           398.9               
2020-05-25           390.9               
2020-09-11           387.9              
2020-03-27           399.2            
2020-07-30           387.2               
2020-08-05           377.1
```

third data frame

```
df3
Date        990986_125003_AA1234
2020-01-01         435.8 
2020-05-25         438.8  
2020-09-11         436.8     
2020-03-27         431.5
2020-07-30         422.5
2020-08-05         432.7
```

I have searched in google and stack overflow but they only showed me to reshape the columns with calling header's name or index or iloc.

can someone please help me to reshape the data frame with satisfy condition.
Thanks

Comment: you also have `990986_125002_CD5627` in the columns, which it belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {}

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
for index, item in enumerate(df.columns.tolist()[1:]):
    if "1250" in item.split("_")[1]:

        dict1["df"+str(index)] = df[['Date', item]]

for keys in dict1.keys():
    print(keys)
    print(dict1[keys])
```

This will create your desired answer as per the given test data.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. when I run above code I got error message saying 'IndexError:list index out or range'.

Comment: I have changed the list and it says  'AttributeError:'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'. Error happens in 6th line

Comment: Hello, you can remove line number 6 and try it again. It is not in use. Try again and let me know whether it works.